# "Tune to <something>" - does it make sense?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I am wondering if saying "tune to this music" would make sense?
Guitars can be tuned to particular note, can people tune to song, or music, or idea?

Google doesn't return many results for "tune to" so I guess it sounds strange, but I found a song "Tune to the Music" by *Status Quo*.
I am asking this question because I am looking for a name for new web site related to music and songs and *tune-to* also came to my mind.

Comment: When I was young, before digital radios and Pandora, you tuned *into* a radio station.

Comment: You can tune the analog dial of a radio so that its sound is not distorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the lyrics for "Tune to the music", the song where you got this from. And, as I suspected, here "tune" is not a verb, but a noun.

> [There's no tune to the music](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Status_Quo%3aTune_To_The_Music)

This means something like "There is no melody/harmony in this music." 
Regarding to your question, you could use maybe use "tune in to the music" as it is described [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tune+in) and also more broadly to "turn attention to the music", so to speak to "let it in".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to ask. Sorry. In any event, tune means to adjust. So you could *tune a musical instrument* or *tune the radio to BBC* or *tune in to a particular program, etc.*

So your use of *tune to* is fine if *this music* refers to something more like BBC, CNN, a music channel, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you tune your radio into a radio station, you adjust the receiver frequency of your radio into that frequency so that they are the same.

When it comes to tuning *into music*, "tune your mood into this music" or "tune your tempo into this music" sounds better to my ears. But I'm not a native English speaker.

Otherwise, the phrase "tune in" may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @TrevorD Now that you mentioned, it sounds odd. I think I'll remove that bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have heard the expression **to tune *into* a [particular] sound**, but only rarely.

It could be used in a situation where there are several background, distant, or otherwise faint sounds and you are trying to (or asking someone else to) concentrate on or pick out *one particular* sound amongst the mixture of faint sounds.